# Firing the application_start for a plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have the plugin architecture described http://www.squarewidget.com/pluggable-architecture-in-asp.net-mvc-4

This appears to be working fine, but now I need the plugin to be able to modify some aspects of the host, in my case, to add a new role to the Roles.

I think the best place for the role to be added would be in the application_start of the plugin's global.asax, but it seems that is not being fired.

I have very limited knowledge of ninject, which is how the plugin architecture is managed, but I am assuming I need to put something in the RegisterServices of the NinjectWebCommon.cs which is in my host.

How do I force my plugin's global.asax to be called when my application is started?

This is MVC4. C#
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at the NinjectWebCommon.cs file you will notice some attributes at the beginning `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` and `WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod` (or maybe just `WebActivator.` depending on your version)

`WebActivatorEx` is the library allowing to execute code automatically upon events of the application's lifecycle.

What you have to do is "jsut" adding a MyModuleStartup.cs file in the App_Start folder of your module with the following code :

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyModule.App_Start.MyModuleStartup), "Start")]
namespace MyModule.App_Start
{
    public static class MyModuleStartup
    {
      public static void Start()
      {
         MyBusinessClass.RegisterMyCustomRole("MyNewRole");
      }
    }
}
```

You may have to test `PostApplicationStartMethod` instead of `PreApplicationStartMethod` if you need your app to be completely set-up before adding your new role.

Comment: Thank you. This works (though I have an issue that is out of scope of this question). Initially, I could not find WebActivatorEx, as it was not referenced in my plugins project (it had no reason to be). Added the reference and now it calls.

I did also find that all of my using statements had to be inside the namespace.